# Not able to create Web application in Visual studio 2003

Tags: visual-studio-2003

I am not able to create new web application through Visual studio 2003. when i am trying to create web application i am getting an error  like "Cannot find the components for communicating with the FrontPage server extensions". Bu at the same time i can create windows application.
Please help me on this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would check you definately have Front-Page extensions installed on your web server. In the control panel go to *Add/Remove Programs* and switch to the *Add/Remove Windows Components*. Double click *Internet Information Services (IIS)* and you will see *Front Page Server Extensions* listed. It should be checked, if not then check it and accept changes, you will need your install media to complete the update unless they were copied to your hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

You could try reinstalling Visual Studio 2003.  It sounds like some DLLs might have disappeared.

Comment: yes even i felt the same.So i reinstalled VS 2003.but even after i am getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

I have uninstalled both IIS and VS2003 and then installed IIS followed by VS 2003...
now it is working fine..
Problem was because of i installed VS2003 first and then IIS...
so make sure we have to insatll IIS first..
Thanks